# Is an iPad keyboard case that operates via Bluetooth compatible with Mac mini?

Tags: mac, keyboard, bluetooth, ipad, mac-mini

I am heading overseas for a year and taking my Mac mini with me, I am also about to get an iPad. I feel it would be best to get an iPad case that has a Bluetooth keyboard with it and was wondering if the Bluetooth keyboard would work with my Mac mini as well that way I don't have to take a keyboard that would just take up more room in my luggage.

Comment: If it’s a Bluetooth keyboard, it should technically work fine. That said, it might not have all of the keys that a full-sized Mac keyboard might have. I would recommend you just buy a cheap Macally 103 key full-size USB keyboard. Cost is less than $20 and it’s a full-sized keyboard which most Bluetooth keyboards aren’t. It’s also very lightweight so it won’t take up much weight in your luggage. And if you don’t want it any more when you travel back home? Just give it away or donate it to charity since it’s less than $20 anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will look into the keyboard you have suggested.

Comment: If you want cheap Bluetooth keyboards, I recomment Goodwill or similar thrift store.  I have picked up old iPad Bluetooth keyboards for as little as $2 to use for a variety of projects.  They are often glued to their case, but with some a little effort and glue remover, they make great extra wireless keyboards.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Bluetooth keyboard, then yes, it'll work with any device that supports Bluetooth keyboards.

However, you'll want to keep in mind that the keyboard layout on a keyboard meant for a tablet may not be ideal for use with a computer. It's not uncommon for these keyboards to leave out keys which aren't useful on a tablet, or to have strange added keys which get in the way. (For instance, a portable keyboard I've got here has "undo" and "redo" keys in place of the right shift key.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into other keyboards as well as the tablet keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

my advice if you still are looking is logitech. they have in my experience the most mac friendly bluetooth keyboards. here's my real world setup.
logitech (built in rechargeable battery via usb cable provided) model K811.

has three function buttons. you can assign three devices to it and switch between effortlessly. F1 is my appleTV. F2 is my iPad and F3 is my MacBook Pro. battery lasts nearly a month per charge, as small and light as they could make it and I've recommended it to dozens of friends over the years and all were thrilled.

amazon has plenty but keen shopping will score one for around 75-80$. ignore those charging 120 or even 200+. best wireless keyboard I've ever owned.